# Jump to the next line that has a statement after an if()

Tags: vim, regex, ide

A previous dev liked to put single statements on the same lines as their relevant `if()`s. I'm trying to find these lines now to fix them! I thought that the following regex would find them, but it isn't:

```
/\^\s*if\.*;\$

/    Start search
\^   Beginning of line
\s*  Any amount of whitespace
if   Beginning of the if() statement
\.*  Any amount of characters
;    The end of the single statement
\$   End of the line
```

So, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Beginning of the line is simply `^`, not `\^`. Similarly, end of the line is simply `$`.

Comment: Thanks. The line `/^\s*if\.*;$` isn't finding any patterns, either.

Comment: `.` is a metacharacter meaning any character. `\.` matches only a literal `.`. Your code probably does not contain `if.` literally

Comment: Thank you garyjohn and RedGrittyBrick! That solved it! Please post that as an answer so that I could accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashed caret `\^` matches a literal caret `^` not the start of a line

**Generally characters with special meanings are called metacharacters, escaped metacharacters usually match the literal character and lose any special meaning.**

Though beware of other contexts, in Perl regex `(` is a capturing parenthesis metacharacter but in awk that role is given to `\(`

Comment: In the end I had to remove the leading backslash from the `^`, `.`, and `$` characters. Thanks!